# Can't change sprite of child gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the sprite of the child gameobject named "top" to another one form the sprite array "part",
but when I run the code:
-the current name of the sprite shows up in the console
-nothing happens

```
public class maker : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public Sprite[] part;

    Sprite top;
    Sprite mid;
    Sprite bot;
    
    void Start()
    {
        top = transform.Find("top").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        mid = transform.Find("middle").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        bot = transform.Find("bottom").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        Debug.Log(top); // returns the name of the current sprite
        top = part[5]; // nothing happens
    }
}
```

Inspector view of the child:

[image: inspector view of the child]

The parent:

[image: the parent]

I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time now and I couldn't find a solution online that would work.

Comment: it may not, if there are other "top", "middle", or "bottom" else where in the scene it will try do that.  Second, you get a copy of the sprite, you change it to part[5] but you never apply it to be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your `SpriteRenderer`'s `sprite` property, instead of just write a sprite to the variable, you created.

```cs
public class maker : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Sprite[] part;

    private SpriteRenderer top;
    private SpriteRenderer mid;
    private SpriteRenderer bot;
    
    void Start()
    {
        top = transform.Find("top").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        mid = transform.Find("middle").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        bot = transform.Find("bottom").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        top.sprite = part[5];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I understand my mistake now